# Set image to the max height of grid

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, grid-layout

In my XAML I have a listview. The item template of the listview contains a grid. This grid has 4 columns and 2 rows. Like so:
[image: xaml item template]

I want the left column be filled with an image and a colored bar under the image. My core problem is that the image will most of the time determine the height of the item. While the image max height is supposed to be defined by the rest of the item. So minimal 100 (Grid `MinHeight="125"` - `Height="25"` of the rect). Or larger if the text makes the item larger. But the text is supposed to define the height of the item. Not the image.

My current xaml is the following:

```
<Grid MinHeight="125">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=BitmapImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=Distance, Converter={StaticResource DistanceConverter}}" FontSize="16" />
    <Image Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="/Images/appbar.next.rest.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="24" Height="24" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why the -1 on my question? Any comments? I dare you to comment! I double dare you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/07/binding-actualheight-and-actualwidth.html contains information on how to do this, accounting for the fact that in Silverlight, `ActualHeight` commonly gives a value of `0`.

From there, if you need to subtract 25 pixels, you can:

- Write a converter (an object that implements `System.Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter`)
- Add an instance of the converter into the Resources of the page/window.
- Add `Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=25` to your binding.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: What grid? The grid the image is in? or the Grid everything including the imageGrid is in?

Comment: The grid that the image is in.

Comment: Well that sucks,, it gives me 0 as actualheight

Comment: Binding to ActualHeight in Silverlight (and thus windows phone) is a known issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522231/silverlight-grid-stackpanel-canvas-actualheight-and-acutalwidth-is-0

Comment: That link that you posted... they've got a workaround included, take a look at the 'workaround' tab. Details are at `http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/07/binding-actualheight-and-actualwidth.html`. I'm editing my answer to include this accordingly.